# ¿Por qué solo envia un request de actualización y no toda mi trama en python?

Tags: python

Llevo rato tratando de descifrar que puede estar ocasionando que en mi request solo actualice un solo sku,cuando en mi consulta estoy enviando varios sku´s y solo actualiza uno.

> ```
>  cursor.execute("SELECT [sku],[quantity]FROM [Analytics].[dbo].[test]")
>     b2b = cursor.fetchall()
>     print(len(b2b))
>     print(b2b)
>     #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
>
>     
>     url = "https:localhost/api/test"
>
>
>     payload = json.dumps([{       
>        
>         "sku": b2b[0][0],
>         "quantity":b2b[0][1]
>      
>         }])
>         
>     headers = {
>       'dsdsdsds',
>       'Content-Type': 'application/json'
> }
>
>
>     response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
>
>     print(response.text)
> ```

Este es el response del api

> [{"jobId":3400726,"sites":"All sites stock update
> requested","status":"success","msg":"Stock update
> enqueued","sku":"A000255 198263
> ","quantity":2}]

Lo que estoy enviando desde la consulta de sql es esto: u

```
('1000255 198264', 2),
  ('1000255 198259', 3), 
  ('1000255 198261', 3),
  ('1000255 198267', 3),
  ('1000255 198262', 3), 
  ('1000255 198263', 2),
  ('1000255 198258', 1),
  ('1000259 198268', 3),
  ('1000259 198273', 1),
  ('1000259 198270', 3)]
```

y solo actualiza este sku:

```
"sku":"A000255 198263",                                              
 "quantity":2}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Por lo que entiendo en el payload lo que debes enviar es un array de objetos algo similar a esto?

```
[{"sku": "1000255 198264","quantity":2}, {"sku": "1000255 198259","quantity":3}, ...etc]
```

Si ese es el caso, el problema está en que solo estás enviando el primer tupla de b2b,y podrías construir el array con objetos así:

```
payload = [{"sku": x[0], "quantity": x[1]} for x in b2b]
```

Comment: Antillon, muchas gracias amigo, tenias razón tuve que iterar el array para enviar las tuplas.